# Two qubit state + Depolarizing channel = Bell diagonal state?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, density-matrix, bell-basis, depolarizing-channel

In multiple sources, e.g. [RGK](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0502064.pdf), [KGR](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.95.080501?casa_token=nHKPuJlj_5cAAAAA%3ArWMQwDLRObR4htYOHIAD4-X2xf1wpUAoE3iI17SCWxxsARLEBV5hiCjNmfd6agCx0az3crk-8V4Kyb8),  it is stated (without proof) that  if you take any two qubit state and send it through a depolarizing channel, the resulting state would be a [Bell-diagonal state](https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/bell-diagonal-state). I understand that a bipartite Bell-diagonal state $\rho_{AB}$ has the form:

$$
\rho_{AB} = \lambda_1 |\Psi^+\rangle\langle \Psi^+| + \lambda_2 |\Psi^-\rangle\langle \Psi^-| +\lambda_3 |\Phi^+\rangle\langle \Phi^+| +\lambda_4 |\Phi^-\rangle\langle \Phi^-|,
$$
where $|\Psi^+\rangle, |\Psi^-\rangle, |\Phi^+\rangle, |\Phi^-\rangle$ are the usual Bell states.
The action of a depolarizing channel $\mathcal{E}$ on two qubits is defined as:

$$
\mathcal{E}(\rho_{AB}) = \sum_i (E_i \otimes E_i) \rho_{AB} (E_i \otimes E_i)^\dagger,
$$
where $E_i \in \{\mathbb{I}, \sigma_x, \sigma_y, \sigma_z\}$ are the Pauli operators.
However, I don't see why *ANY* bipartite density operator would be transformed into a Bell-diagonal state. Is there any proof of this claim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, note that every Bell state $|\psi_{ij}\rangle=(|0i\rangle+(-1)^j|1\bar i\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$ is an eigenstate of $E_i\otimes E_i$ for all $i$ (the eigenvalues are either $\pm 1$). Hence, a Bell-diagonal state remains Bell-diagonal under the action of the map. This already suggests that a Bell-diagonal state is likely to be the ultimate destination of the map, but let us prove that.

Consider an arbitrary state $|\Psi\rangle$. This can be decomposed in the Bell basis,
$$
|\Psi\rangle=\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}|\psi_{ij}\rangle.
$$
We have $XX|\psi_{i1}\rangle=-|\psi_{i,1}\rangle$ and $XX|\psi_{i0}\rangle=|\psi_{i,0}\rangle$. So, for example, if I calculate
$$
|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|+XX|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|XX,
$$
then this knocks out any cross terms such as $|\psi_{i0}\rangle\langle\psi_{j1}|$

Similarly, $ZZ|\psi_{0i}\rangle=|\psi_{0,i}\rangle$ and $ZZ|\psi_{1i}\rangle=-|\psi_{1i}\rangle$, so terms such as $|\psi_{0i}\rangle\langle\psi_{1j}|$ will also be knocked out. Ultimately, the only terms that are left are $|\psi_{ij}\rangle\langle\psi_{ij}|$, i.e. the state is Bell diagonal.

Strictly, to put all this together carefully, you want to say
$$
\rho_x=\rho+XX\rho XX
$$
and
$$
\mathcal{E}(\rho)=\rho_x+ZZ\rho_xZZ
$$
two see how the two separate steps that I've made fit together.

Comment: awesome! thanks a lot @DaftWullie...

Comment: Hello @DaftWullie, could you please comment on how this formulation of depolarizing channel is equivalent to applying the Kraus operator representation of depolarizing channel? Thanks...

Comment: Also, the diagonal elements no longer adds up to 1, don't they? Do I have to renormalize the final density operator?

Comment: The Krauss operators are $\sigma_i\otimes\sigma_i/2$. It's that factor of 2 that makes things properly normalised, so you don't need a separate step at the end.